# Displaying SSMS authorized databases with Filter?

Tags: sql-server

How do I filter out databases that have only my authority on common servers?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the listing by using the following SQL:

```
USE master;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'user_login';
GO
SELECT name, HAS_DBACCESS(name) 
  FROM sys.databases;
GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: thank you :)
But i need to see object explorer
and I see all the databases